# Syntax error in Teradata query: Encountered "WITH

Tags: teradata

I am trying to run the following Teradata (V 14.10.3.09) DB query using Teradata Studio:

```
WITH params AS
(
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') AS w0s -- truncate to the current hour
   ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS w0e
   ,CURRENT_DATE -8 AS w1s
   ,CURRENT_DATE -1 AS w1e
)
SELECT ST_NM
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN CRT_DTTM>=w0s AND CRT_DTTM<w0e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Call_Volume_This_hr
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN CRT_DTTM>=w1s AND CRT_DTTM<w1e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/7.0 AS Avg_Call_Volume_Past_Week1
     ,CASE WHEN Call_Volume_This_hr < Avg_Call_Volume_Past_Week1 THEN 0
           ELSE Call_Volume_This_hr -Avg_Call_Volume_Past_Week1
      END AS VARIANCE
     ,(100 * VARIANCE) / Avg_Call_Volume_Past_Week1 AS Percentage_Variance
FROM XDW_V.INB_CALL_NRT_RPT
WHERE CRT_DTTM>=w1s
  AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CRT_DTTM)=EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND ST_NM IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ST_NM;
```

But getting the syntax error:

```
SQL Editor: Encountered "WITH params AS. Was expecting one of: "alter" ... "call" ... "create" ... "drop" ... "dump" ... "logging" ... "replace" ... 
 "replication" ... "restart" ... "restore" ... ";" ... "dynamic" ... "explain" ... "lock" ... "locking" ... "with" ... "with" "recursive" ... "with" "(" ... "(" ... "validtime" ... 
 "current" ... "transactiontime" ... "nontemporal" ... "as" ... "select" ... "sel" ... "retrieve" ... "ret" ... "cd" ... "modify" ... "give" ... "rename" ... "cm" ... "delete" ... 
 "del" ... "release" ... "revalidate" ... "rollback" ... "rollforward" ... "checkpoint" ... "insert" ... "ins" ... "update" ... "upd" ... "merge" ... "set" ... "commit" ... 
 "abort" ... "begin" ... "bt" ... "end" ... "et" ... "ct" ... "grant" ... "cv" ... "revoke" ... "help" ... "show" ... "mload" ... "execute" ... "exec" ... "comment" ... "collect" ... 
 "database" ... "echo" ... "ss" ... "diagnostic" ... "initiate" ...
```

I tried a few random things like removing "WITH"and replacing "AS" with "IS" which I know is not very good effort. Can someone suggest me what should be the correct syntax for this type of query as I think I am missing something related to syntax.
UPDATE: What I am trying to do is (forgot to add in original post)

1. If CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is say 2015-08-20 16:27:42.987 Then
   fetch count(*) grouped by each state where Create_time is between
   2015-08-20 16:00:00.000 to 2015-08-20 16:27:42.987.
2. Second
   step is to find count(*) grouped by each state for past 7 days
   (Aug/13 to Aug/19) during the same 1 hour  window 16:00:00.000 to
   17:00:00.000 and take sum of count(*) for past 7 days, and average
   count(*) (divide sum by 7).
3. Third step is if the count(*)
   for today (calculated in step1) is greater than average count(*)
   then find the difference and display in a column (say Variance) and
   also calculate percentage deviation by using (Variance/average
   count(*)) * 100 and display in a column say percentage.

UPDATE: For no more spool space error I used advice to use inner join and the query started fetching result as expected. So the final query I am using now is:

```
WITH TEMP_TAB (w0s,w0e,w4s,w4e) AS
(
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') AS w0s
   ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS w0e
   ,CURRENT_DATE -29 AS w4s
   ,CURRENT_DATE -1 AS w4e
)
SELECT ST_NM
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN CRT_DTTM>=w0s AND CRT_DTTM<w0e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Call_Volume_This_hr
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN CRT_DTTM>=w4s AND CRT_DTTM<w4e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/28.0 AS Avg_Call_Volume_Past_4Weeks
    ,CASE WHEN Call_Volume_This_hr < Avg_Call_Volume_Past_4Weeks THEN 0
           ELSE Call_Volume_This_hr -Avg_Call_Volume_Past_4Weeks
      END AS VARIANCE  
     ,100 * VARIANCE / Avg_Call_Volume_Past_4Weeks AS Percentage_Variance 
FROM XDW_V.INB_CALL_NRT_RPT INNER JOIN TEMP_TAB
ON 1=1
WHERE CRT_DTTM>=w4s
  AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CRT_DTTM)=EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND ST_NM IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ST_NM;
```

Comment: For your syntax error, you need to define your column list for your CTE, like so:  `WITH params (w0s,w0e,w1s,w1e) as select...`

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I corrected query by adding (w0s,w0e,w1s,w1e) and now it doesn't show any syntax error. 
But on running the query I get "No more spool space" error.
On searching for the reason behind this error on net, it looks like spool space allocated to the user name I am using to connect to the DB is less than what the query requires.
I'll try to find from the DB admin and post the update.

Comment: You might find that you use less spool space if instead of using a CTE, you just stick in the values you need directly into your CASE and WHERE bits like `,SUM(CASE WHEN CRT_DTTM>=TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') AND CRT_DTTM<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `. My fear is that Teradata is sucking up spool space for your implicit Cross Join, where a Cross Join simply isn't needed here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion JNevill. I updated the post with final query I am using (with inner join) to avoid spool space error.